Are there any recommended note-taking software with the following requirements?
Are there any recommended note-taking software with the following requirements?

Similar to Capacities, taking objects as the basis.
There can be different types of relationships (links) between objects, and then based on the different types of relationships, the links show different colors.
It is possible to filter and display nodes and links for the links.


